# G1ANT Advanced lesson 4

Tags: g1ant

I would like to share my experience while setting up the mail.imap command in G1ANT studio.

For everyone stuck at the invalid credentials error--

1. Open your gmail account (the one you ware using in your code)
2. Go to the settings tab to the top right corner and then click on See all Settings.
3. In the All settings option click on Forwarding and POP/IMAP
4. Enable IMAP
5. Now head over to you homepage and click on manage accounts tab for your email account.
6. In the manage account section click on Security
7. Scroll down and turn on access to LESS SECURE APPS
8. Let the site update and go back (Do not close the tab directly)

This procedure should fix the invalid credentials error. However, even after doing all this the LIST variable (where the email data is stored) has no value allocated in it.

If anyone can find a solution to this problem, your help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think your messages are already seen, so you can unread them and then try again and also see that you have got some messages that are from the current day.

Thank You for your solution for Invalid Credentials.